# Extract individual records from Rows object Web2py

Tags: web2py

I have the following db table:

```
db.define_table('game', Field('video', 'upload'),
                Field('pics', 'upload'),
                Field('answer'))
```

Field `pics` and Field `answers` each have 6 records. The `video` Field only have 1 record. I have to display a `pics` record and the 6 records from `answer` then the user will have to pick the right `answer` record to match the displayed `pics` record.

The `Controller`:

```
def test():
    rows = db().select(db.game.ALL, limitby=(0, 6), orderby='<random>')
    pic_row = rows[random.randint(0,4)]
    session.pic_id = pic_row.id
    return dict(rows=rows, pic_row=pic_row)
```

I have this in the `View` for `test.html`:

```
<h1>{{=pic_row.pics}}</h1>

{{for row in rows:}}
<h4>{{=B(LI(A(row.answer, _href=URL('show_test', args=row.id))))}}</h4>
{{pass}}
```

After each click on the `answer` the user is sent to `show_test.html` and from `show_test.html` the user will come back 5 more times to `test.html`. I want to display a new record (image) from `pics` 5 more times but the `random` won't work because it could repeat the same record more than one time. How can I display the 6 records from `pics` one record at the time, each time the page is visited without repeating any of the records? The other related question is that I want to show the `video` only the first time the user visits the `test.html`.

I would like to learn how to do do this,I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    if not session.pic_id:
        session.pic_id = []
    rows = db(~db.game.id.belongs(session.pic_id)).select(db.game.ALL, limitby=(0, 6), orderby='<random>')
    pic_row = rows.first()
    session.pic_id.append(pic_row.id)

    if not session.already_visited:
        #Do something to show your video....
        session.already_visited = True     # Change it to true so it doesn't run this piece of code again

    return dict(rows=rows, pic_row=pic_row)
```

That solution would save all the previous exhibited pictures on the session and would randomly retrieve a picture only once. I'm not sure if that is what you really wanna do, since after the 6 pictures, there would be nothing else to show to the user.

Comment: thanks for your help with this, I tried your solution but it's showing an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'` for this line: `session.pic_id.append(pic_row.id)`

Comment: My bad! My negation in the DAL query was wrong. Could you try it now ?

Comment: now I get this error: `TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable` for this line : `rows = db(db.game.id.belongs(session.pic_id)).select(db.game.ALL, limitby=(0, 6), orderby='<random>')`

Comment: I have been trying to use `random.sample()` to fix this issue but I havn't been able to do it because `random.sample()` outputs a `list`, not an `int`

Comment: At this point, session.pic_id should be a `list`, which is an iterable. I'm not sure of what is going on, but you shouldn't use `random.sample()` as a part of your solution

Comment: Yes, I know, I gave up the idea of using `random.sample`. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Btw, are you setting a value to session.pic_id anywhere besides the line `session.pic_id.append(pic_row.id)` ?

Comment: hmm. I delete `session.pic_id` in `def show_test():` but I don't think that's the issue in `def test():`